# Is Teiid can use VIEW as the RDBMS does?

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, teiid

[Teiid](http://www.jboss.org/teiid/) is a data virtualization system that allows applications to use data from multiple, heterogenous data stores.

We know SQL in RDBMS has such a feature: produce a view which including columns from different tables.

Does Teiid has the same feature when integrate data from different data source.

For example, there is a flat file data source with a schema (id, book_name), and a rdbms data source with a schema (id, price). Is there any solution to make a integration schema(id, book_name, price) in Teiid?

Answer (score 1):

Teiid has the ability to create views manually using DDL allowing you to bring together columns from different tables/data sources.

For a small example have a look here: http://teiid.blogspot.com/2012/03/dynamic-vdbs-are-back-with-punch.html

Currently I have been doing all views manually on dynamic VDBs, there is also the Teiid Designer (eclipse plugin) that can make the creation of views much easier.

Thanks

Comment: In your small example, there is only one data source. Can DDL be used to combine two different data sources? For example, there is a flat file data source with a schema (id, book_name), and a rdbms data source with a schema (id, price), is there any solution to make a integration schema(id, book_name, price) in Teiid? Thx!

Comment: Yes, it can support any data source, check http://teiid.org for supported data sources, if not there one can be added by implementing an exposed API.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can combine the data from any number of sources. Yes, your example of flat file and RDBMS is one of the first quick start examples. See https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/teiidexamples/Data+Federation+Example